# Blocking IPs from a database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to block IPs from a database I created and I tried something like this:

```
<?php
$deny = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT ip FROM blocked_ips WHERE id=1'),MYSQL_ASSOC);
if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {
   header("location: http://www.google.com/");
   exit();
}
?>
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What happens? Is there an error message?

Comment: Why are you querying with `WHERE id=1`?

Comment: That's the thing, nothing happens. I used my own IP and I don't get redirected.

Comment: @SimoV8 because I wanted to block only the ip form the database with that id.

Comment: You need to match the IP, not the ID. Look at my answer for the easiest way to do this. This assumes you table has ip addresses in the `ip` column of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query `SELECT ip FROM blocked_ips WHERE id=1` won't select more than one row if id is your primary key. You should be using `SELECT ip FROM blocked_ips` (without the id) instead for an actual array of data.

The logic you are using:
`$deny = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('SELECT ip FROM blocked_ips WHERE id=1'),MYSQL_ASSOC);`
can only return one row of data and thus makes no sense to be combined with:
`if (in_array ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $deny)) {`
since mysql_fetch_array is meant to be called in a loop to grab all the data.

I believe the logic you were trying to write was aiming for a loop like so:
`while($row=mysql_fetch_array(..))`

But such a solution is slow... you should be SELECTing from the database based on the ip as VIDesignz suggested.

```
<?php
$ip=mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$query="SELECT * FROM blocked_ips WHERE ip='$ip'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){
   header("location: http://www.google.com/");
   exit;
}
?>
```

Buuuuuut, the `mysql_*` functions are depreciated. Please use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: I understand now, and tried the code you gave and still nothing happens. I can't seem to figure out what I did wrong, again.

Comment: Perhaps you're getting depreciated warnings splashing to the user's browser resulting in a "headers already sent" error when trying to change the location header. Maybe `error_reporting(0);` would help. If not, please debug the code one piece at a time. Perhaps the query is erroring, did you connect to the database successfully and select a database to work on? `if(!$result){echo mysql_error();}` if no luck with that, make sure the query runs in phpmyadmin for your given ip address: `echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` Make sure `echo mysql_num_rows($result);` returns "1" for a blocked ip.

Comment: I did everything you said to verify that it works. I tried to echo the ip selected from the database and it displays 'Resource id #9' ,not the actual ip. That's why it doesn't work I guess, how do I solve this?

Comment: Nevermind, I managed to make it work! :D Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just try to select the ip address itself?

```
 $user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

 $query = 'SELECT ip FROM blocked_ips WHERE ip=$user_ip';
```

If you get a result (>0) then it exists in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto the previous answer, you can select the IP address with MySQL and check the number of rows returned.

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$sql = "SELECT ip FROM blocked_ips WHERE ip='$ip'";
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($sql))>0) {
   header("location: http://www.google.com/");
   exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't work either, nothing happens at all, but i understand the code.